# Why must initialize smallest representable number for REDUCTION clause for MAX in OpenMP?

Tags: openmp, reduction

I read a initialization rule for variables included in reduction clauses in OpenMP, from the pdf:

### Parallel Programming in Fortran 95 using OpenMP, 2002.

In the table 3.1, it is said that for MAX operation, the init value should be smallest representable number.

So it means I have to use the smallest representable number in my computer for the specific type of variables?? Why cannot just use a variable that is enough for the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Using the smallest possible numbers ensures that whatever other value you pass will be higher and MAX will use return that one instead of the default one.

If you where to use another value and then MAX gets called with a value smaller than that, which is possible, MAX will return the initial/default one.

You may consider that to be purely academic, but if you still need to pick an initial value why not use the only one that works on all cases?

Comment: Until someone persuade me, otherwise I will only use !OMP PARALLEL WORKSHARE, with MAX inside, rather than use REDUCTION. Because doing so can avoid thinking about the "smallest representable number".

Comment: @PabPeter That's a completely ridiculous position that demonstrates you really don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: Update: I find that it does not have to be smallest representable number. And I compared the two(Reduction(MAX:a) with WORKSHARE +MAXVAL with a code of find the max value in a 1D arrary with 10000 elements, which turns out that the latter one give better performance. @Jeff I am at the beginning of learning OpenMP step by step and I am an active learner. Once I feel something wrong I will ask. I am foolish and hungry. :)